# BigQuery - create a table and populate with data

Tags: google-bigquery

With BigQuery is it possible to set up and populate data into a table defined as part of a 'WITH...' statement?

Like...

```
> with table1 as (    
   select id,title from (  
>      {1,'Fred'),
>      {2,'Joe'),
>      {3,'Mary'),    ) as tt )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with table1 as (
  select 1 as id, 'Fred' as title union all
  select 2, 'Joe' union all
  select 3, 'Mary'
)
select * from table1
```